# What should you do when you see the OP, writing the answer in the question itself?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

For instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200035/return-instancetype-in-swift) the OP has copied and pasted the accepted answer into his question. I have seen this behavior in 1 out of every 200 questions. I don't suspect any foul intentions but it disrupts the clarity of the question.

Should I edit the question by deleting the 'copy/paste answer'? Or what?

Comment: Just roll it back. An answer has nothing to do inside a question and just confuses other users. If the OP found the answer he should post it as an answer or accept the one which solved his problem.

Comment: If he found the answer in the mean while, he should answer it, but for "fairness" he have to accept the answer of someoneelse (no rule actually enforcing it).

Comment: @DarioOO No, OP needs to accept the answer that best solves the problem. Even if it's their own. If another answer actually solved things, they wouldn't need to write their own.

Comment: @DarioOO Either an answer solves OP's problem or not. There is no "fairness" that OP needs to accept an answer from someone else that would be just dumb.

Comment: I mean exactly that, I sometimes foudn the answer my self, but added it only after sometime or after having accepted another answer. That's because everyone could post questions and answers, but I think the site goal is to primarily resolve problems, not making points. Also because sometimes an additional answer could still provide very valuable

Comment: @DarioOO Your last sentence is correct, that additional answers, especially that explain things in different terms, can be valuable. But the goal of the site is not to resolve problems, but instead to create a high quality repository of questions and answers. If a person wants to share their knowledge, they can post the answer with their answer by clicking a checkbox and filling in the answer box that pops up. There's no expectation that you cannot accept your own answer or that you need to wait to post your own answer.